# Getting 404 not found without .www

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm getting 404 Not found when visiting my website page without appending the .www at the beggining of the site.

When accessing https://bhumblelaw.com => (NOT FOUND)
when accessing https://www.bhumblelaw.com => index.html shown (OK)

Here's a screenshot of my rewrite cond which was autogenerated with certbot after allowing it to redirect.

[image]

/etc/apache2/sites-available/bhumblelaw.conf

Comment: Can you share your server.config or whatever file you use for URL redirections?

Comment: @AmitVerma Sure, However I don't use a .htacesss file so i'm not sure what other file would use URL redirections.  Where is the server.config located at?

Comment: Try adding this line to virtual host file `ServerAlias *.bhumblelaw.com` just bellow the existing `ServerAlias www.bhumblelaw.com`  Your `virtual host` file is the one that you shared as an image with the question.